# Apply a function to a numpyarray with checks each element in order to know what result to return

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following function:

```
def Leaky(x):
    if(x > 0):
        return x
    else:
        return 0.01*x
```

and the following numpy array:

```
a = np.array([[-1,2],[-3,4]])
```

How can I apply the "Leaky" function to the "a" numpy array and get rid of the error which it gives:

> "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()".

Desired output:

```
[[-0.01,2],[-0.03,4]]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `numpy`, the best way to dot his is with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(a>0, a, 0.01*a)

array([[-0.01,  2.  ],
       [-0.03,  4.  ]])
```

---

The problem with you code is that when you're doing:

```
a > 0
array([[False,  True],
       [False,  True]])
```

As you can see you're getting an array with the same shape as `a`, as you're applying the condition to all values in `a`, hence the result of the operation is ambiguous

Comment: Thank you, this helped!